# Facebook Graph API Post to facebook page issue after posting

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

*I am using facebook graph api  to post on my facebook page through gmail, there everything is 100% perfect and i successfully posted all emails to my facebook page*

**The issue is**

After posting on facebook no one can see those posts, neither other page admins, nor the audience who liked the page ( Only i can see those posts)

I created everything from my facebook ID.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue or tell me why is this happening so that i can resolve it and my audience can see those posts on my page. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your app is in dev mode, you have to set it live - otherwise any content created through it will only be visible to other people that have a role in the app.

Comment: my app is already live .. and it show green color there which indicates that its live

Comment: Are you sure this is in relation to the app status, and not something else, like reviewed permissions? Also double-check you are using the correct app id.

Comment: yes i am sure about it and i double verify the app iD again nothing happens yet